# Get/Search reference of element in set

Tags: python, set

Well for a custom object I have a custom `__eq__` and `__hash__` function, that is only dependent on an unique "name". Object of this class are then placed into a set.

Now I would like to search/find an element in the set:

```
class Resource:
    def __init__(self, name, rest)
        self.name = name
        # ....

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name

s = {Resource("test", 10), Resource("test2", 20)}
```

How could I then search for the object with "equality": `test`? As a last resort I could use dictionaries, but that would be quite ugly since the "key" would be stored at two places which can lead to difficult bugs.

---

Just to clarify: I am not looking for "in" I'm looking for a way to return the reference.

Comment: What do you mean? Try `Resource("test", "dummy") in s`, it returns `True`

Comment: @thefourtheye Well instead of testing whether an item is "in" the set I wish to return a reference - so I can check/modify it's other variables. (And do anything else).

Comment: You cannot get the items from a `set` (even if you get, with something like `tuple({Resource("test", 30)} & s)[0]`, it is not guaranteed that you will get the actual item in the set, because from `set`'s point of view, if two objects are equal, then they are one and the same. So, it may return the object being used in the checking). I would recommend the dictionary approach for this.

Comment: @thefourtheye if you could put that into an answer I can accept it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @thefourtheye; for the example class you have shown, a `dict` probably would be the better option here. If your use case really requires a `set`, then you could make a special class that is a cross between a `dict` and a `set`:

```
import collections

class MySuperSpecialSet(dict, collections.MutableSet):
    def __init__(self, it=[]):
        for v in it:
            self.add(v)

    def add(self, v):
        super(MySuperSpecialSet, self).__setitem__(v, v)

    def discard(self, v):
        try:
            super(MySuperSpecialSet, self).__delitem__(v)
        except Exception:
            pass

    # make sure some `dict` methods are hard to call by accident
    __setitem__ = None
    keys = iterkeys = viewkeys = None
    items = iteritems = viewitems = None
    values = itervalues = viewvalues = None
    copy = None
    fromkeys = None
    popitem = None

    # some MutableSet methods that should override dict methods
    pop = collections.MutableSet.pop
    update = collections.MutableSet.__ior__


s = MySuperSpecialSet([Resource("test", 10), Resource("test2", 20)])

test2 = Resource("test2", 2)
test2_orig = s[test2]

test2.rest == test2_orig.rest  # False
```

For the sake of efficiency, you would need to manually implement a few methods from `collections.MutableSet`, but this barebones class can do pretty much everything a built in `set` can do as well as a few things a `dict` can do (like `__getitem__`, which is what you need for the behavior you are asking for).

I would also suggest you make your hash a little more unique, so that you don't have hash collisions with strings. Something like this would work:

```
class Resource(object):
    def __init__(self, name, rest)
        self.name = name
        # ....

    def _key(self):
        return (type(self), self.name)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._key())

    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return self._key() == other._key()
        except AttributeError:
            return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Sets are basically containers which are generally used to collect unique items. They are not ordered and the individual elements are not directly accessible. So, getting an element from a set is not possible.

One possible solution would be using set intersection operation, like this

```
{Resource("test", 30)} & s
```

and the result will be a `set` again. So, you may want to convert that to a list or a tuple and then access the element from it. For example,

```
common = {Resource("test", 30)} & s
if common:
    result = tuple(common)[0]
```

Even now, `result` need not be the object which is in the `set` already. From the `set`'s point of view, the `Resource("test", 30)` and `Resource("test", 10)` are one and the same because they both are equal as per the comparison logic. So it can choose to return either of them. There is no guarantee that you will get the corresponding object from the `set`.

---

PS: For this usecase, I would recommend using a dictionary, as you mentioned in the question itself.